# C# Can't connect to MySQL server

Tags: c#, mysql

I am having problems connecting to my SQL (online) server from my program.

I get the error

> “A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.“

I think my connectionstring is correct...

```
    myConnection.ConnectionString =
    "SERVER=" + db_host + ";" +
    "DATABASE=" + db_name + ";" +
    "UID=" + db_username + ";" +
    "PASSWORD=" + db_password + ";";
```

My router has forwarded the port that the sql server uses.
The db_host is the IP of the server.
The db_username is a user for the sql server (not root@localhost)

I am not sure if I need to enable external connections to the DB?
I heard they were open by default, and I can't find anywhere in phpmyadmin or cpanel to enable it.

Been trying various solutions for this specific error, but no luck.
The program times out from trying to connect and throws the exception
*System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904)*

**EDIT**
Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.
I am using MySQL .NET Connector class now, and I receive the error
Authentication to host 'x.x.x.x' for user 'myusername' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user 'myusername'@'my_external_ip' (using password: YES) ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Access denied for user 'myusername'@'my_external_ip' (using password: YES)

The IP x.x.x.x is the MySQL server's IP.
myusername is where my username is and my_external_ip is this PC's external IP.
The password is correct. So does this mean external connections are disallowed by the host?

Comment: go to this site for examples on how to connect 
[ConnectStrings](http://www.connectionstrings.com)

Comment: uh, you're talking sql server, phpmyadmin is for mysql...

Comment: I bet that you are using a SqlConnection instead of a MySqlConnection class. Show the code that raises the exception

Comment: @MadsM see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection` to connect to MySql server

Try to use `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection`

More info [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-connection.html)

You can download the MySql Connector [here](https://www.mysql.com/products/connector/)

2nd Question

In MySql a user is a combination of the username and the host that user is connecting from. So you need to add a user to your server like `user@x.x.x.x`

See more [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html)

Comment: Thank you (and the other commenters). My bad, I used the wrong class. I downloaded the connector class and tried to connect, however I get a new error. Please see first post

Comment: @MadsM I think you will need to open the MySql port (usually 3306) to the Ip you want to connect from.

Comment: I have updated my connectionstring so that it looks like this server=x.x.x.x;database=dbname;User Id=username@xx.xx.xx.xx;password=mypw, however I still get the same error as I edited in above

Comment: You have to have that user in MySQL server

Comment: the user does exist. I made it for this reason, and it has the permissions required.